# Translating "value in array column" MongoDB query to MongoDB Spring Data code

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

How can I translate the following MongoDB query into Java-based query using the Java MongoDB Spring Data driver?

```
db.User.aggregate([
{ $match : { $expr: { $in: [ "ADMIN", "$roles" ] } } },
{ $sort : { "createdAt": 1 } },
{ $limit : 1 }
])
```

My attempted solution in Kotlin, which I think is wrong (I don't know how to specify that "roles" is a field in the User document).

```
fun queryFirstAdmin(): User? {

    val matchRolesOpt = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("ADMIN").`in`("roles"))
    val sortOpt = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdAt")
    val limitOpt = Aggregation.limit(1)
    var ops: MutableList<AggregationOperation> = mutableListOf()
    ops.add(matchRolesOpt)
    ops.add(sortOpt)
    ops.add(limitOpt)
    var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(*ops.toTypedArray())
    val aggregationResult = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User::class.java, User::class.java)
    return aggregationResult.uniqueMappedResult
}
```

This solution works but unfortunately it returns a slice of the User document (since it has been unwound):

```
fun queryFirstAdmin(): User? {
    val unwindOpt = Aggregation.unwind("roles")
    val matchRolesOpt = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("roles").`is`("ADMIN"))
    val sortOpt = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdAt")
    val limitOpt = Aggregation.limit(1)
    var ops: MutableList<AggregationOperation> = mutableListOf(unwindOpt, matchRolesOpt, sortOpt, limitOpt)
    var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(*ops.toTypedArray())
    val aggregationResult = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User::class.java, User::class.java)
    return aggregationResult.uniqueMappedResult
}
```

i.e. if the Document returned has the array ["ADMIN"] but the original document has ["ADMIN","USER] in the "roles" field

How can I fix this?

Comment: Alright, you start and we'll help you along the way when you get stuck.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack overflow isn't a site that just gives you answers to problems you haven't even attempted.

Comment: I got this so far: (kotlin code)

val matchRolesOpt = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("ADMIN").`in`("roles"))
val sortOpt = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdAt")
val limitOpt = Aggregation.limit(1)

Comment: roles is actually an array column and i want to match any arrays that contains the string "ADMIN"

Answer (score 0):

The **MongoDB Spring Data** Java code for the aggregation:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(where("roles").is("ADMIN")),
        sort(ASC, "createdAt"),
        limit(1L)
);
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "User", Document.class);
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**NOTE:**

The match stage in the aggregation

```
{ $match : { $expr: { $in: [ "ADMIN", "$roles" ] } } }
```

can be replaced with this and the result is the same:

```
{ $match : { roles: "ADMIN" } }
```

---

The same query using [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/):

```
Bson match = match(expr( Document.parse(" { $in: [ 'ADMIN', '$roles' ] } ")));
// -or- 
// Bson match = match(eq("roles", "ADMIN"));

List<Bson> pipeline = 
        Arrays.asList(match, sort(ascending("createdAt")), limit(1));

List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(results); 

results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Its great!